# Migration from billing library 3 to 4 / 5 - Why a single purchase is associated with multiple skus/ multiple products?

Tags: android, android-billing

In billing library 3, a single `Purchase` is associated with single sku

```
purchase.getSku()
```

However, in billing library 4 and 5, a single `Purchase` is associated with multiple sku/ multiple products

```
purchase.getSkus()

purhcase.getProducts()
```

Does anyone know, what does it really mean by a single `Purchase` is associated with multiple skus/ multiple products? How can a user perform single purchase operation, and ended up with multiple paid items?

Answer (score 0):

At Google IO 2021 they introduced "multi-line" subscriptions, meaning you could sell multiple products in a single subscription purchase.